# UI Automation for Flash Games

Tags: flash, testing, unit-testing, automation

has anyone used or heard of a good selenium-like toolset for doing automated UI testing with Flash? I would ideally like to have the ability to record and playback events against my game and integrate this into our build server.

Comment: I use [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) for things like this.